# For Pinescript, how to combine two alerts into one?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I need assistance for the following issue:

In my code below, two seperate orders need to be closed to reduce the overall position size. Pinescript executes this code perfectly, but in doing so, it also sends two seperate alerts. My current platform, Finandy, can't process two simultaneous webhook requests for some reason.

```
if (_tp_price >= close)
    strategy.close(id=str.tostring(last_order_id))
    strategy.close(id=str.tostring(first_order_id))
```

The requirement is to send only one webhook alert that reduces the position size by the combined quantity of these two orders, and also close both the trades for Pinescript calculations.

Comment: Why not use `alert_message` for one of them only?

Comment: It can be done, but it's not intuitive. Strategy relies on multiple entry and exit points, and uses TV paratmeters such as '{{strategy.order.contracts}}'
Also. the webhook message keeps changing depending on the settings on the recieving platform, so it'll entail changing the 'alert_message' and calculations throughout the code instead of just changing the signal message.
Combining two alerts into one can be done by 'strategy.close(....., qty = total_qty) for one order and cancelling the other? Can't figure a way of cancelling the executed order.